# What is the Groovy syntax for Liquibase preconditions?

Tags: xml, groovy, liquibase, mysql5

> **Summary**

I have to add a column on a table if it does not exist.

Column Name: *myColumn*

Table Name: *myTable*

Using the Groovy language and Liquibase, I want to check for column existence and create it if it does not exist.

> **Liquibase**

**XML**

Based on my searches, the XML fashion to accomplish this would be:

```
<changeSet id="myChangeSet" author="me">
    <preconditions onFail="WARN">
        <not>
            <columnExists tableName="myTable" columnName="myColumn" />     
        </not>
    </preconditions>
    <addColumn tableName="myTable">
        <column name="myColumn" type="text" default="null" />
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

**Groovy**

As for the Groovy version, I am unsure and there is no known way for me to test it.

```
changeSet(id:'myChangeSet', author:'me') {
    preconditions(onFail:'WARN') {
        not() { 
            columnExists(tableName='myTable' columnName='myColumn') 
        }            
    }
    addColumn(tableName:'myTable') {
        column(name:'myColumn' type:'text') {
            constraint(default:'null')
        }
    }            
}
```

And I am unsure about the Grrovy syntax on how the upper XML version would translate into Groovy.

How would the XML changeset would translate into Groovy, tell me?

Comment: If you are already using Liquibase, you really don't need to have the precondition.

Answer (score 1):

There some minor issues with your groovy conversion of the change set:

- Groovy (and the Liquibase DSL) are case sensitive
- Tag attributes should be passed as a Groovy Map using ':' instead of '=' and need a comma between them
- "default" (or one of the variants like "defaultValueComputed") is an attribute of column and not a child

See below a corrected version:

```
changeSet(id:'myChangeSet', author:'me') {
  preConditions(onFail:'WARN') {
    not { 
      columnExists(tableName: 'myTable', columnName: 'myColumn') 
    }            
  }
  addColumn(tableName: 'myTable') {
    column(name: 'myColumn', type: 'text', defaultValue: null)
  }            
}
```

In addition I think it would be better to invert the precondition to state "if the column is already there we have nothing to do":

```
preConditions(onFail:'MARK_RAN') {
  columnExists(tableName='myTable' columnName='myColumn') 
}
```

That way it will not be executed over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Your changeset looks good IMO, but I don't know the 'default' attribute, neither for the [column](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html), nor the constraint tag. The equals behind tableName and columnName should also be a colon.
However, if the XML version runs, I would say the groovy version will also run.

You can omit the round brackets in the `not` line.
You also might want to change the `onFail` value to `MARK_RAN` so liquibase will not attempt to run it next time.

I would test the change in the following order:

- use your Test DB without the column
- let the changeset run
- look into the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table and search for the changeset. You should see `EXECUTED` in the `EXECTYPE`column and something nice in the `DESCRIPTION` column. Check if the DB has been modified as expected.
- delete the column of the changeset in the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table and start your application/rerun the changelog. The changeset will run again.
- take another look into the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table. Now you should see the row again, but the `EXECTYPE` should be `MARK_RAN`.